# Anchor is not clickable in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a button/link which is not clickable in IE but is in Microsoft Edge and other modern browsers.

Can't see whats wrong with the code. Any ideas?

```
<div class="bttn">
<a href="2.html">Next page</a>
</div>

.bttn{ margin:50px 0px 0px 50px }
.bttn a{ padding:10px 30px; }   
.red-btn{ padding:10px 30px; background-color:#C10931; color:#fff;  }
```

Comment: How is it styled?  Can you include any CSS that would affect either the div or the anchor in your post?

Comment: How does it look when you view the source in IE?

Comment: When viewing the source in IE the link is being parsed.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to expect help. Clearly the problem is not with that simple markup.

Comment: So it looks exactly like you've written above in the source code?

Comment: Yes. I never experienced this issue and have no clue why IE is not allowing to click it.

Comment: I think this is probably going to be closed, as not enough information has been provided, and there's nothingwrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: Create a blank HTML file, and try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Better yet, there are online tools just for this: http://jsbin.com/mizukowoxo/1/edit?html,css (output: http://output.jsbin.com/mizukowoxo/1)

Answer (score 0):

in your head tag add the following code.(Assuming you have an external css cheat).

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
/* css for IE 8 */
</style>
<![endif]-->

 <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <![endif]-->
```